# Linux hangs after rebooting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, bash, shell

I have a script that needs to run at boot time, I set it up using update-rc.d and now when I reboot the system with `sudo reboot` the system hangs during the boot process. But if I restart the system manually the system does not hang during reboot. Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this could be happening?

Here was my process with setting up the script to run at boot time:

1. created LSB init script called `collection.sh` located in `/etc/init.d`
2. executed `$ sudo update-rc.d collection.sh defaults 99` to create necessary symlinks.

And this is what it does:

`collection.sh` simply calls another script located in my home directory called `start.sh`. Then `start.sh` spawns two new processes that have a specified working directory. It looks something like this:

```
#!bin/bash
(cd path/to/working/dir; ./start_script1.sh && ./start_script2.sh)
```

`start_script1.sh` should run for about 24 hours while `start_script2.sh` runs in an infinite loop.

The problem I have is that this system could potentially need to be rebooted, but currently the system hangs during the reboot if these processes are running.

here was the output of the update-rc command:

```
 Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/collection.sh ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K99collection.sh -> ../init.d/collection.sh
   /etc/rc1.d/K99collection.sh -> ../init.d/collection.sh
   /etc/rc6.d/K99collection.sh -> ../init.d/collection.sh
   /etc/rc2.d/S99collection.sh -> ../init.d/collection.sh
   /etc/rc3.d/S99collection.sh -> ../init.d/collection.sh
   /etc/rc4.d/S99collection.sh -> ../init.d/collection.sh
   /etc/rc5.d/S99collection.sh -> ../init.d/collection.sh
```

So any thoughts on what my problem is? Also if I left out anything that could be useful let me know.

Comment: *"But if I restart the system manually..."* -- Please clarify.  Do you mean a cold boot, i.e. shutdown then power-on?

Comment: @sawdust Yes I mean using the power button

Comment: Are your scripts executing the start_scripts in the background?

Comment: *"but currently the system hangs during the reboot if these processes are running."* -- Instead of repeatedly writing *"reboot"*, be more specific and indicate if the hang is during the shutdown or the boot.

Comment: @sawdust doesn't the code in `start.sh` start the processes in a new shell and then exit? thus `start_script1.sh` and `start_script2.sh` will run in the background?